# ngx-smart-modal parameters are not working in angular5

Tags: angular5

I am using 'ngx-smart-modal' version of 3.1.0 in my angular5 app with the help of [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-smart-modal).When I given the default parameters mentioned in the official tutorial it's not working.

```
  <ngx-smart-modal #myModal identifier="myModal" dismissable="false">
   <h1>hello</h1>
 </ngx-smart-modal>
```

in the above code I trying to give the dismissable parameter as false for preventing the closing of modal when clicking on backdrop,but it's not working.How can I pass these parameters in ngx-smart-modal ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Property binding. This is not an issue with 'ngx-smart-modal'

```
[dismissable]="false"
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As Anjula said, this is a property binding issue, not an issue with the library itself.

You have several ways to pass data into a component (e.g. the `identifier` option):

- `identifier="myModal"`
- `[identifier]="'myModal'"`

In the two above examples, the value received by the component will be the `'myModal'` (as a `String`)

But here:

- `option="false"`
- `[option]="false"`

The first example will pass the data as a boolean (`false`) and the second example will pass it as a string ('false').

All property binding without `[...]` will pass the data as a `String`.

The `[dismissable]` options waits for a boolean value, so the only way to send it as a boolean is that form: `[dismissable]="true/false"`.

The full documentation about the available options is [here](https://github.com/biig-io/ngx-smart-modal#parameters--options). For each option the awaited type is marked between parentheses.